# What is the most efficient way to search in XML files with Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, web-applications

I have a web app written in Perl. Now I would like to add a new feature, which needs to visit some XML files (about 200) and parse out some information to show on the web page. I used `XML::Path` package to search the XML files one by one, but this is just too slow. Do you have some suggestions to accelerate this process?

Comment: XML::LibXML is probably the fastest option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can at least get an idea of how long it takes by using either [App::xml_grep2](https://metacpan.org/release/App-xml_grep2) (for [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML)) or [xml_grep](https://metacpan.org/module/MIROD/XML-Twig-3.42/tools/xml_grep/xml_grep), which come with [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig). Both will be faster than using XML::XPath, with XML::LibXML being the faster of the 2.